# Why is initial state being set over and over again in the "useState" hook of react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component

I have created a function which is listening for the resize event it checks for the window width and updates my IsMobile variable if(width<=600 and IsMobile = false) then set it to true and vice versa.

here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export interface MechnicalLiftProps {
}

const MechnicalLift: React.SFC<MechnicalLiftProps> = () => {

    const [IsMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(true)

    const handleWindowChange = () => {

        console.log('window inner width', window.innerWidth);
        console.log('is mobile in handle', IsMobile);

        if (window.innerWidth <= 600 && IsMobile === false) {
            setIsMobile(true);
            console.log('is mobile set to true');
        }

        if (window.innerWidth > 600 && IsMobile === true) {
            setIsMobile(false);
            console.log('is mobile set to false');
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mount running');
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowChange)
        handleWindowChange()
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowChange)
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('is this mobile ', IsMobile);
    }, [IsMobile])

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default MechnicalLift;
```

my console output:

[image]

i feel initial state is being set every time the component is re rendered otherwise why is IsMobile set to true every time in handle window change even though its set multiple times to false. new to hooks please elaborate your explanation as much as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the empty array on the `useEffect`, you are setting up the event listener exactly once, on the first render. The function you create has a reference to `IsMobile` from that first render, and it's value is `true`. Its value will never change.

If you need to know the most recent value of the state, you can use the callback version of set state:

```
const handleWindowChange = () => {
  setIsMobile(prev => {
    console.log('previous value', prev);
    if (window.innerWidth <= 600 && prev === false) {
      return true;
    }
    if (window.innerWidth > 600 && prev === true) {
      return false;
    }
    return prev;
  });
});
```

By the way, setting state won't rerender if the value didn't change, so you don't need to guard against setting it to a value that it already has. In other words, if you don't need the logging, then your code can be simplified to this:

```
const handleWindowChange = () => {
  setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 600);
}
```

Comment: from what i gathered, use Effect will run as did mount if you keep the array empty and i thought to add the event listener once when the component mounts and to remove that event listener like i do in component will unmount. Sorry but i don't get the reference part could you may be provide a link or something for further reading on this. so IsMobile in functional component is not same as this.state.IsMobile in class based component.

Comment: In function components, your state is represented by *local* variables. Note that `IsMobile` is a `const`; it will never change. So the only way you get a new state value is by rendering again and creating a new local `const`. Since you create the callback function only on the first render, that callback function only has the first local variable in its closure. For more info on closures [see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)